# Finding bound counting primes which end by $3$

Tags: prime-numbers

I am trying to count the number of prime numbers which end by digit "$3$" such as $3, 13, 23$, etc. and are below $10^6$.

The number of primes existing below $10^6$ is known empirically to be $78~ 498$. Because, at most 1 every 10 numbers ends by the digit 3, it means that, **at most** there could be $7850$. So this is the lowest bound I have found so far.

Is this lower bound correct?
I thought so, but when trying to answer in a questionnaire, it is said my result is wrong:
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: it seems you lost a 0 you start with 78.498 and finsh with 7.850. btw if the distribuition of last digit is unifor I will divide this number by 4 getting 19.000 primes

Comment: Why would you divide by $10$?  Even if you (inappropriately) assume that the primes are as uniformly distributed as possible, the only digits a prime $>5$ can end with are $\{1,3,7,9\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For primes greater than $5$ the last digit is always $1,3,7,$ or $9$.  Any other last digit means the number is divisible by $2$ or $5$.  They are approximately equally distributed so you would have about $19,500$

Comment: Thank's! However, that is not an answer to my question. My question is what is wrong in my simple reasoning.

Comment: You give no justification to your division by $10$.  You say "at most" 7850, which would imply that there must be 7849 or 7850 ending with each digit, but we know there are none or 1 ending in each of six digits.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I found the mistake. My mistake was thinking that at most 1 of every 10 number in 78 498 prime numbers below $10^6$ could be 3. Because those do not include all numbers, but only the ones which are primes.